# Typescript React stateless function with generic parameter/return types

Tags: reactjs, generics, typescript

How to define **generic type** in React stateless components based on **parameter**, or outside configuration?

Example component:

```
interface IProps<V> {
  value: V;
  doSomething: (val: V) => void;
}

const Comp: React.SFC<IProps<number>> = <T extends number>({
   value: T,
   doSomething
  }) => {
 return <div />;
}
```

Above example will work, but only with numbers as values.

Is possible to do upgrade to achieve something like:

```
const Comp: React.SFC<IProps<??>> = <?? extends string | number>({
   value, /* of type ?? */
   doSomething
  }) => {
 return <div />;
}
```

So that we can decide whatever we want numbers, or strings when using component.

Desired usage:

```
// This should setup generic type to string
<Comp value="string" ... />

// Or number
<Comp value={123} ... />

// Should be compilation error as we cannot use * on 'text' * 5
<Comp value="text" doSomething={val => val * 5} />
```

Edit: Should do same job as `function` does:

```
 function Comp <T>({value, doSomething}: IProps<T>) { ... }
```

SFC Type has definition:

```
interface SFC<P> {
  (props: P & { children?: ReactNode }, context?: any): ReactElement<any>;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to do this in TS 2.3. The point is to use 2 types for "inside" and "outside" of that component.

```
interface IProps<V> {
    value: V;
    doSomething(val: V): void;
}

// type "inside" component
function _Comp<T>(props: IProps<T>) {
    return <div />;
}

// type for "outside" of component
interface GenericsSFC extends React.SFC<any> {
    <T>(props: IProps<T> & { children?: React.ReactNode }, context?: any): JSX.Element;
}

const Comp = _Comp as GenericsSFC;

// dont type check: v is of type "hey"
<Comp value={"hey"} doSomething={v => v - 1} />;
```

Comment: Seems to work, just am curious if there isn't some easier way.. Also `GenericsSFC` needs IProps which are typed inside component, so probably best to keep also GenericSFC inside...

Probably best may be to keep only typed function and do not use SFC at all for generics :o

Comment: Is there any better of of doing this now? Typescript has added some support for generics in JSX in 2.9