# Type of Generic Stateless Component React? OR Extending generic function interface in typescript to have a further generic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics

**Problem**: The interface of `Stateless Functional Component` is given as

```
interface SFC<P = {}> {
    (props: P & { children?: ReactNode }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null;
    propTypes?: ValidationMap<P>;
}
```

The prop type of my component is also generic as:

```
interface Prop<V>{
    num: V;
}
```

How to properly define my component? as:

```
const myCom: <T>SFC<Prop<T>> = <T>(props: Prop<T>)=> <div>test</div>
```

gives an error at `character 27` that `Cannot find name 'T'`

Here is :[Typescript Playground of modified example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20FunctionalComponent%20%3C%20P%20%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09(props%3A%20Readonly%3CP%3E%2C%20context%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09%09displayName%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%09defaultProps%3F%3A%20Partial%3CP%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20Prop%3CV%3E%7B%0D%0A%09num%3A%20V%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20Search%3A%20FunctionalComponent%3CProp%3CT%3E%3E%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(props)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%2010%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

**MyFindings**:

1:Typescript 2.9.1 support Stateful Generic Component: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#generic-type-arguments-in-jsx-elements

```
class myCom<T> extends React.Component<Prop<T>, any> {
   render() {
      return <div>test</div>;
   }
}
```

2: Extending `SFC` to make a new interface as mentioned in following answer would make component's prop type as `any`:
[Typescript React stateless function with generic parameter/return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392479/typescript-react-stateless-function-with-generic-parameter-return-types#) which I don't want. I want to give proper type for my prop

Comment: What happens if you replace the generic `<T>` with `<T extends {}>` ?

Comment: same error. As I want something like:`const myCom: <T>SFC<Prop<T>> `

Comment: I added playground link in description @JonasW.

Comment: @NamanKheterpal I encountered the same prob and investigated a bit of time for that. You can find my solution, how to declare and how to use a React SFC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848828/how-to-create-stateless-functional-components-that-accept-generics/51585233#51585233)

Answer (score 60):

You can't use generics like this:

```
const myCom: <T>SFC<Prop<T>> = <T>(props: Prop<T>)=> <div>test</div>
```

The TypeScript spec states:

> A construct of the form
>
> ```
> < T > ( ... ) => { ... }
> ```
>
> could be parsed as an arrow function expression with a type parameter or a type assertion applied to an arrow function with no type parameter.

[source; Microsoft/TypeScript spec.md](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#411-arrow-functions)

Your declaration doesn't match the pattern defined in the TypeScript spec, therefore it wont work.

You can however don't use the SFC interface and just declare it yourself.

```js
interface Prop<V> {
    num: V;
}

// normal function
function Abc<T extends string | number>(props: Prop<T>): React.ReactElement<Prop<T>> {
    return <div />;
}

// const lambda function
const Abc: <T extends string | number>(p: Prop<T>) => React.ReactElement<Prop<T>> = (props) => {
   return <div />
};

export default function App() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Abc<number> num={1} />
            <Abc<string> num="abc" />
            <Abc<string> num={1} /> // string expected but was number
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can this pattern be somehow used if you have intersection type with `React.FC`? For example I'd my component to be able to take type arguments but also have composite components. Currently I have const lambda fn component `const Table = React.FC<TableProps> & { Row: React.ComponentType<RowProps> }` And I'd like to be able to use a type param when using this component.

Answer (score 27):

There's a pattern to mitigate this issue by declaring generic component type alias outside of component and then simply asserting it when you need it.

Not as pretty, but still reusable and strict.

```
interface IMyComponentProps<T> {
  name: string
  type: T
}

// instead of inline with component assignment
type MyComponentI<T = any> = React.FC<IMyComponentProps<T>>

const MyComponent: MyComponentI = props => <p {...props}>Hello</p>

const TypedComponent = MyComponent as MyComponentI<number>
```

Comment: This probably does not serve the purpose of generics. Developer may need to rewrite functionality of every component and cannot have a common behaviour. 
`const MyComponent: MyComponentI = props => <p {...props}>Hello</p>` This line would be repeated for every component.

Comment: This worked perfect for me in some cases and I think it is nice, however, we don't have access to the type inside the component/function, which is limiting in other cases. I'm curious is there is a way around that (besides using chris' answer)

Answer (score 17):

Factory pattern:

```
import React, { SFC } from 'react';

export interface GridProps<T = unknown> {
  data: T[];
  renderItem: (props: { item: T }) => React.ReactChild;
}

export const GridFactory = <T extends any>(): SFC<GridProps<T>> => () => {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};

const Grid = GridFactory<string>();
```

#### UPDATE 08/03/2021

To avoid rules of hooks errors you have to finesse the syntax like this:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

export interface GridProps<T = unknown> {
  data: T[]
  renderItem: (props: { item: T }) => React.ReactChild
}

export const GridFactory = <T extends any>() => {
  const Instance: FC<GridProps<T>> = (props) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(props.data)

    return <div>...</div>
  }

  return Instance
}

const Grid = GridFactory<string>()
```

Comment: Is `<T extends any>` used to avoid TS to treat it as type assertion? Smart idea.

Comment: that is correct.  it can extend another type here too if thats needed

Comment: I do not get it... what would it mean here to "treat it as type assertion"? would you please explain it a little bit or provide some example of what happens withouth that `extends any`? I am googling about this but cannot find the right direction. Thanks! @BruceSun & @chris

Comment: @RocíoGarcíaLuque Sorry I was wrong, it is to avoid TS compiler to treat it as JSX but not "type assertion". Checkout [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-function-component-with-generic-types-37db71) and its readme file to see this in real example.

Comment: @BruceSun ahhhh such a silly thing :D thanks a lot for the codesandbox, I was struggling to understand that code bit... cheeers

Answer (score 10):

The Factory pattern presented here by @chris is great but I can't use React Hooks with it.
So I'm using this one.

```js
// Props
interface Props<T> {
  a: T;
}

// Component
export const MyComponent: <T>(p: PropsWithChildren<Props<T>>) => React.ReactElement = props => {
  return <div>Hello Typescript</div>;
};
```

If you don't need children you can remove PropsWithChildren part.
Props decomposition and hooks work as well.

```js
export const MyComponent: <T>(p: Props<T>) => React.ReactElement = ({ a }) => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false);
  return <div>Hello Typescript</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm proposing a similar yet albeit slightly different solution (brainstormed with a friend). We were trying to create a Formik wrapper, and managed to get it working in the following fashion:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

export type FormDefaultProps<T> = {
  initialValues: T;
  onSubmit<T>(values: T, actions: FormikActions<T>): void;
  validationSchema?: object;
};

// We extract React.PropsWithChildren from React.FunctionComponent or React.FC
function component<T>(props: React.PropsWithChildren<FormDefaultProps<T>>) {
  // Do whatever you want with the props.
  return(<div>{props.children}</div>
}

// the casting here is key. You can use as typeof component to 
// create the typing automatically with the generic included..
export const FormDefault = memo(component) as typeof component;
```

And then, you use it like:

```
 <FormDefault<PlanningCreateValues>
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        initialValues={PlanningCreateDefaultValues}
      >
         {/*Or any other child content in here */}
        {pages[page]}
</FormDefault>
```

I haven't been able to achieve this with method expressions:

`const a: React.FC<MyProp> = (prop) => (<>MyComponent</>);`

Comment: I went your way and `values` argument in `onSubmit` is always unknown. Do you have any idea where I may went wrong?

Answer (score 8):

i have a way to do, but I'm not sure is perfect or not

```
interface ComponentProps<T> {
    text: T;
}

export const Component= <T,>(props: ComponentProps<T>) => {
  const { text } = props
  const [s] = useState(0) // you can use hook
  return (<div>yes</div>)
}
```

you can use component like this:

```
 (
  <>
    <Component<string> text="some text" />
  </>
 )
```

Comment: You defined `CategoryRelationProps` but you're using `ComponentProps `

Comment: thanks for @refaelio , i changed my answer with correct props.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have React's FunctionComponent type included in the type definition (to get the return type automatically typechecked, for example), you can use a construct like this if you don't mind repeating the types a bit:

```
interface MyProps<T> {
  val: T
}

const Component: React.FC<MyProps<any>> = <T>({
  val
}: MyProps<T>) => {
  // Your code and hooks here
  return <div>Heya</div>
}
```

The type of the const `Component` is `React.FC<MyProps<any>>`, meaning that you can use it with any valid value for the `MyProps` type parameter `T`, but since the implementation re-specifies the generic type parameter `T` inside the implementation code its type is `T` and not `any`, and thus it will be typechecked properly. `T` might have restricting specifiers like `extends string`, you just need to repeat them in both the interface specification and the function implementation signature.

Answer (score 0):

An example of generic stateless component according to jmattheis's post.

#### MyGenericStatelessComponent.tsx

```
import React from "react";

type Prop<T> = {
    example: T;
};

const MyGenericStatelessComponent: <T extends Record<string, number | string>>(props: Prop<T>) => JSX.Element = <
    T extends Record<string, unknown>
>(
    props: Prop<T>
): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <div>
            Example Prop id: {props.example.id}, Example Prop name: {props.example.name}
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyGenericStatelessComponent;
```

#### Usage:

```
<MyGenericStatelessComponent example={{ id: 1, name: "test01" }} />
```

Comment: Your example is just a function that returns an element. Also, OP updated his question with the preferrable way starting from TS 2.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Using `T = any` as @vadistic example works but you will not have any type checking. Use this code and you will have code completion and type checks.

```
interface IProps<TModel> extends RouteComponentProps {
    headerText?: string | React.ReactNode;
    collection: TModel[];
}

interface ICommonSortableType extends ISortableItem {
    id: number;
    isCorrectResponse: boolean;
}

interface ISortableItem {
    sortableId: number;
}    

type GenericFunctionalComponent<TModel> = React.FC<IProps<TModel>>;
const CommonSortableList: GenericFunctionalComponent<ICommonSortableType> = (props) => {
...
}
```

Can then be used like this:

```
class CommonSortableType {
    public sortableId: number = -1;
    public id: number = -1;
    public isCorrectResponse: boolean = false;
}

<CommonSortableList
    collection={item.commonSortableTypes} //Is CommonSortableType[]
    headerText={<FormattedMessage id="item.list" />}
</CommonSortableList>

class ExtendedOptionDto extends OptionDto implements ICommonSortableType {
    public sortableId: number = -1;
}

class OptionDto {
    public id: number = -1;
    public isCorrectResponse: boolean = false;
}

<CommonSortableList
    collection={item.extendedOptionDtos} //Is ExtendedOptionDto[]
    headerText={<FormattedMessage id="item.list" />}
</CommonSortableList>
```